# Unique projective line through any two distinct points in projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I’ve just started studying projective geometry and this is the first result we are proving. By the way, $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and I write $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for the projective space associated with $V$. I also define a projective line in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ as $\mathbb{P}(U)$ for any subspace $U$ of $V$ with dimension $2$.

**Theorem I’m trying to show:**

Through any two distinct points $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, there is a unique projective line $L$.

**My attempt**

Let $P=[p]\neq Q=[q]$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$. Then the vectors $p,q$ are linearly independent. So $\langle p,q \rangle$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $V$, hence $\mathbb{P}\langle p,q \rangle$ is a projective line in $\mathbb{P}(V)$.

Now I’m struggling to show explicitly that this projective line, call it $L$, contains $P,Q$ and that it is unique in doing so.

Well, $\langle p,q \rangle$ has 1-dimensional subspaces $\langle p\rangle$ and $\langle q \rangle$, so $\mathbb{P}\langle p,q\rangle = \{\langle p\rangle, \langle q\rangle \}$.

Am I right in saying that $\langle p\rangle=[p]$, and therefore $L$ contains $P,Q$.

I have no idea how to prove uniqueness.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I believe you are defining $\mathbb{P}(V)=V\setminus\{0\}/k^\times$.

The answer $\mathbb{P}(\langle p,q\rangle)$ is correct.

The notation $[p]$ denotes the equivalence class associated to $p$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$. So, I would not say that $[p]=\langle p\rangle$, but rather that $[p]$ is the image of $\langle p\rangle\setminus\{0\}$ in the natural map $V\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V)$.

Edit: The natural map is the one that takes a non-zero vector $v\in V$ to its equivalence class $[v]\in\mathbb{P}(V)$.

From this it should be clear to see that $[p],[q]\in \mathbb{P}(\langle p, q\rangle)$ becasue $\langle p\rangle\subset \langle p, q\rangle$ and $\langle q\rangle\subset \langle p, q\rangle$.

Next, the statement $\mathbb{P}(\langle p, q\rangle)=\{[p],[q]\}$ is not exactly correct. For instance $[p+q]\in \mathbb{P}(\langle p, q\rangle)$ (which is not equal to the other two points).

The last thing to show is the uniqueness. Suppose $W\subset V$ is also a 2-dimensional vector space such that $[p],[q]\in \mathbb{P}(W)$. Then, $p,q\in W$ and hence $\langle p, q\rangle\subset W$. Comparing dimensions tells you that $W=\langle p,q \rangle$.

Hope this clears any confusion.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Just one question. What is the natural map you mention? Could you write it explicitly? That would help me

Comment: Does the above edit help?